# Regex to find word with exact count of any letter

Tags: java, python, regex

I have a list of words:

1. *"abac"*
2. *"abcc"*
3. *"acb"*
4. *"aaaa"*
5. ...

User can input any word for searching in this list.

My goal is to find in list specific word that contains the same count of each character from input word. For example, if an input word is *"abca"* then **only** first word from list should match, if *"cba"* - then **only** third.

I decided to use regex which will be applied to each words in list separately until matching.

My attempt is regex `/^[abca]{4}$/` but this is the wrong approach since it ignores the count of each character therefore second and fourth words from list matching also, though they shouldn't.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: Not a regular language. Regex doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess what you could do is create a `HashMap<(character) char, (integer) count>`, loop through the String and increment the count for each character, then compare the results from the HashMap with each string to see if it matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex doesn't exist for this language because the language is *not* regular.

You'll want to either create a `HashMap<char, int>` that captures the count of each char in the string and compare that to the input string or sort your list of words and the user's input and compare them.